# How to access the subfolder file inside joomla directory?

Tags: joomla

I have joomla directory which i have subfolder name membership and a file. I need to access the membership folder through browser url but accessing i am getting 500 internal server error problem. how to avoid it.

```
for example:
https://example.com // joomla directory with htaccess
https://example.com/membersip/file.php

Output: 500 internal server error
```

Comment: I see `membersip`. Is this a typo question?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be able to access this without issues. But there might be other restrictions in your .htaccess-file.

In my htaccess-file, the following line in the rewrite conditions allows direct access to folders:

```
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Investigate the .htaccess - file in your www-folder to make sure it does not block direct access to subfolders.

Otherwise: the 500 internal server error should leave some error message in the server logs.